# Factor analysis and logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, data-mining, factor-analysis, latent-variable

I have done factor analysis on 18 variables and got a 5 factor solution. 
Denote: $X=(X_{1},X_{2},.....,X_{18})$ as the variables and $F=(F_{1},F_{2},..,F_{5})$ as the factors. Thus we have a loading matrix $L=(l_{ij})$ which is a $18\times5$ matrix where $l_{ij}= {\rm Cov}(X_{i},F_{j})$. So, I computed the factor score component matrix by least squares method which can be computed by using the formula: $\hat{F}=(L^TL)^{-1}LX$. After computing the factor scores for each respondent, I fit a logistic regression model with a response variable (binary variable) on the factor scores and extract the significant factors.

**My Question:**
After the loading matrix have been computed we have:
$$
X_{i}=l_{i1}F_{1}+l_{i2}F_{2}+l_{i3}F_{3}+l_{i4}F_{4}+l_{i5}F_{5}; i=1,2,...,18  \tag{1}
$$
and when we are estimating the factor score component matrix we have:
$$
F_{j}= \alpha_{j1}X_{1}+\alpha_{j2}X_{2}+....+\alpha_{j18}X_{18}; j=1,2,..,5  \tag{2}
$$
While interpreting the factors I came up with the following:
Let's fix $i=1$ in **Equation1** and $j=2$ **Equation2**, then shall the signs of $l_{12}$ and $\alpha_{21}$ be the same $?$ Could anyone justify why or why not the signs would be the same$?$

Comment: Why is this important to know?

Comment: Suppose I have two significant factors $F_{2}, F_{4}$  whose estimates are positive from the logistic regression. Also, $F_{2}$ is negatively loaded by $X_{1},X_{3}$ and positively loaded by $X_{5},X_{7}$; $F_{4}$ is positively loaded by $X_{8},X_{11},X_{13}$.

Comment: Continuing to the above comment: Now say in equation 1 we have sign of $l_{12}$ to be negative and the sign of $\alpha_{21}$ to be positive. Then we claim that from the loading matrix that $F_{2}$ is negatively loaded by $X_{1}$ but from the equation 2 point of view we note that the estimated $F_{2}$ score is positively affected by $X_{1}$. ideally the signs of $l_{12}$ and $\alpha_{21}$ should be the same for the interpretation. Hence there is a confusion created.  It would be helpful if some theoretical details are shared.

Comment: If the binary response variable was not present during the FA, the loadings are not necessarily affected. The sign is related to the angle of the OLS solution in FA. In logistic regression the sign is related to the direction of the predictors. I guess rotation also biases the weights in a way that affects the factor loadings, for say maximal variance. If you rely on the factor loadings for further modelling and try to predict if a var ends up as F1 or F2, that would be circular reasoning.

Comment: Please note that response binary variable was not used while computing the loading matrix, I used it only in logistic regression. So, ideally the $l_{12}$ and $\alpha_{21}$ should have similar signs $?$ If not, then the factor analysis cannot be applied to that data set $?$

Comment: Imagine you had ten different response variables. Some of them could potentially reflect the factor loadings, while most of them probably will not (for example: ice cream consumed [yes, no] ). You need a good theoretical reason why you would expect that an outcome reflects the "variance-optimized" components.

Comment: I could not understand what you tried to explain in the above comment. Could you please explain it a bit more broadly?

Comment: I think it will be more clear to you if you compare text book definitons related to *the purpose* of **logistic regression** and **factor analysis**. The goals of each type of analysis are entirely different.

Comment: Yes I read the definition from the textbook to check about logistic regression and factor analysis. Since there was a multicollinearity issue, I did factor analysis to reduce the 18 variables to 5 factors. Then I fitted the logistic regression model with binary response as dependent variable and the factor scores obtained as independent variables to come up with significant factors, where corresponding to each factor I note the loads of each variable $X_{i}$ on the significant factors and report them. This is what I did. I only wander about the signs to which I don't have an answer.

Comment: I've never come across FA as a solution to mulicollinearity. Common solutions are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Remedies_for_multicollinearity Are you familiar with the sigmoid log function?